# GET route only works with parameter - node.js + express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm very new to node + express and having trouble setting up a get route. When I use a parameter within the route called out below, I am getting data back without any issues. However, when I try to return an object back without the parameter, I get a blank page from postman & localhost:3000.

I initially thought my loop was causing the issue but when I console.log the object I'm attempting to pass in the res.send, it appears just fine.

Below are two of my routes (in this instance, /cards/imgs returns a blank page but /cards/imgs:id path returns the url correctly:

**edit 1: adding code above routes that define of idIndexes in routes.js**

routes.js -

```
const cards = require('C:/Hearthstone/cards.json');
const data = cards["data"];
var idIndexes = [];
var cardClassIndexes = [];

for (let a in data) {
    idIndexes.push(data[a]["id"]);
};

// index the cards by their "cardClass"
for (let a in data) {
    cardClassIndexes.push(data[a]["cardClass"]);
};

module.exports = (app, db) => {
    // get all card image urls
    app.get('/cards/imgs', (req, res) => {
        const imgURL = 'http://media.services.zam.com/v1/media/byName/hs/cards/enus/'
        var imgArr = {};
        for (let id in idIndexes) {
            var cardID = idIndexes[id];
            var imgURL_Temp = imgURL + cardID + '.png';
            imgArr[cardID] = imgURL_Temp;
        };
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(imgArr));
    });

    // get card image url based on id
    app.get('/cards/imgs/:id', (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const imgURL = 'http://media.services.zam.com/v1/media/byName/hs/cards/enus/'
        const imgURL_Temp = imgURL + id + '.png';
        var arr = {};
        arr["url"] = imgURL_Temp
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(arr);
    });

    // get all card information
    app.get('/cards', (req, res) => {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
};
```

Below are the remaining files used for the API

index.js file -

```
const cardRoutes = require('./routes.js');

module.exports = (app, db) => {
    cardRoutes(app, db);
};
```

server.js file -

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const port = 3000;

const routes = require('./app/routes');

require('./app/routes')(app, {});

if (app.listen(port)) {
    console.log("Live on port: " + port);
};
```

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci8O5.png)

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Af8.png)

[localhost:3000/cards/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erLXS.png)

package.json file -

```
{
  "name": "Hearthstone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API for Hearthstone cards",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "start",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "michael gross",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.14.12"
  }
 }
```

Comment: Where and how is variable `idIndexes` defined? Do you get any output in console?

Comment: maybe he has defined it globally or imported else it would throw an error.

Comment: I define it earlier in my routes.js file. It is defined globally above the routes to be able to re-use. Edited original post to add those portions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**idIndexes** is not defined.

```
app.get('/cards/imgs', (req, res) => {
        const imgURL = 'http://media.services.zam.com/v1/media/byName/hs/cards/enus/'
        var imgArr = {};
        for (let id in idIndexes) { //here
            var cardID = idIndexes[id];
            var imgURL_Temp = imgURL + cardID + '.png';
            imgArr[cardID] = imgURL_Temp;
        };
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(imgArr));
        });
```

Comment: OP says that `when I console.log the object I'm attempting to pass in the res.send, it appears just fine`.

Comment: instead of res.send(JSON.stringify(imgArr)); you can try res.json(imgArr); On client side no need to parse again.

Comment: Yes correct it is defined earlier. Have edited original post to add that piece, sorry for the confusion. 
I tried with the res.json as well but unfortunately still getting a blank page on localhost:3000/cards/imgs

Comment: why are you requiring routes twice?

const routes = require('./app/routes');
require('./app/routes')(app, {});

Comment: **res.json({"test":"test"});** try this and see It works or not ?

Comment: Commented out the 'const routes' & tried replacing imgArr with the test object, still getting blank a blank page unfortunately :/

Comment: how are you call can you upload a screenshot .

Comment: Added picture 'cmd' + 'localhost' & what i'm using in my package.json file for this to the original post

Comment: can you try http://localhost:3000/cards/imgs URL. I think I got the issue.

Comment: just tried with that link, same thing. is there something else I should change?

Comment: can you something else instead of /cards/imgs

Comment: put new screenshot of localhost:3000/cards/
also added the get route that creates this uri

Comment: what is was trying to say is instead of /cards/imgs give **/cards/images**, I think it's overriding routes. Not sure but you can try once

Comment: that worked!!! i changed it to **/cardTemp/images/** and the data came back, thank you so much!
Do you know of any way to stop it from overriding the routes?

Comment: not sure but this should work, you can move app.get('/cards/imgs/:id') to top after that app.get('/cards/img);

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your routes.js file like this...

### routes.js

```
module.exports = (app, db) => {
    // get all card image urls
    app.get('/cards/imgs', (req, res) => {
        const imgURL = 'http://media.services.zam.com/v1/media/byName/hs/cards/enus/'
        var imgArr = {};
        for (let id in idIndexes) {
            var cardID = idIndexes[id];
            var imgURL_Temp = imgURL + cardID + '.png';
            imgArr[cardID] = imgURL_Temp;
        };
        res.status(200).send(imgArr);
    });

    // get card image url based on id
    app.get('/cards/imgs/:id', (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const imgURL = 'http://media.services.zam.com/v1/media/byName/hs/cards/enus/'
        const imgURL_Temp = imgURL + id + '.png';
        var arr = {};
        arr["url"] = imgURL_Temp
        res.status(200).send(arr);
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi Kapil, thank you for your response. Tried with the new res.status(200).send(imgArr); but still getting a blank page when trying localhost:3000/cards/imgs